# No feedback on answer from the person who issued the bounty (replicating the problem)

Tags: discussion

In regards to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/677114/deny-application-access-to-hard-drive-or-volume-in-windows-7) I would be interested if my (first) solution works, but I wasn't able to replicate the problem. Where should I ask how to replicate a problem? Seem kind of counter intuitive to do that on super user, since I'm kind of asking for a problem and not a solution?! I'm sort of confused now...

Comment: Just add a note to your answer that you can't fully replicate the issue because you don't have the exact same environment.